# VUE JS Fetch JSON data and display single value in HTML as plain text

Tags: javascript, html, json

i have a `.json` file with the following structure:

```
{
  "d": {
    "value1": "300",
    "value2": "0000000002",
    "value3": "AAAA",
  }
}
```

I want to access `300` in my vue-app and display it as plain text.
That's it.

Question may be stupid, but I don't get it and my code won't work.

Could you give me an example of how to do that?

Greetz,
Simon

app.vue:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#vue-root",
    data: {
        items:[]
    },
    created(){
        this.fetchData()
    },
    methods: {
     fetchData() {
       this.$http.get('test.json')
         .then(result => {
            this.items = result.data
          })
     }
   }
 })
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simon VueJS</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

   <div>
           {{ d.value1}}

     </div>

<script src="app.vue"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include current code using `fetch()` at Question?

Comment: done :) here you can see my files

Comment: Note, have not tried vue.js. What does `d` refer to within `{{}}` ? Should `this.items = result.data` be `this.data.items = result.data`?

Comment: Your index.html should have `{{items.d.value1}}` (and the `data` block in app.vue should declare items as an object, not an array.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
 <div>
           {{ d && d.value1}}

     </div>
```